# Soft magnetic induced magnetization through radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, laser, electromagnetic-induction

Is it possible to induce temporary magnetism upon a soft magnet, such as a soft ferrite, alongside the parallel axis of a laser beam fired at the material? Would the soft magnet need to be electrically conductive or an electrical insulator like ferrite magnets?
If the question isn’t clear, feel free to point it out. This area of physics has always been my weakest so I’m more than prepared to make some major hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean transient magnetization induced by the electric field of light through nonlinear-optical effects, such as inverse Faraday effect. The laser beam has to be circularly polarized though. These things exist in both metallic and dielectric materials.

This magnetization is propotional to the intensity of the laser beam. However, since the latter cannot be increased infinitely (the medium will be destroyed sooner or later), in experimentally feasible conditions this magnetization is quite weak. The common way to verify this transient magnetism is to measure magneto-optical effects with the help of a second laser beam.